# Eloquent scope with where multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to perform a query with laravel scopes.

I have a table "hotels" with id, name, etc. and one table with a lot of features for every hotel, like:

```
Featute.id= 1 name=Wifi Hotel_id = 1
Featute.id= 2 name=Wifi in room Hotel_id = 1
Featute.id= 3 name=Wifi in pool Hotel_id = 1
Featute.id= 4 name=Wifi in room Hotel_id = 2
Featute.id= 5 name=Wifi in pool Hotel_id = 2
```

I want to get all the hotels with "Wifi in room" and "Wifi in pool"

Which method do I need to use in the scope? What would the query look like?

I've tied this already but it returns the hotels with some of this features.

```
select `hotels`.`name` as `name`, 
       `hotels`.`delegation_id` as `delegation`, 
       `hotels`.`jpcode` as `jpcode`, 
       `hotels`.`iata` as `iata`, 
       `hotels`.`checked` as `checked`, 
       `hotels`.`gen_note` as `gen_note`, 
       `hotels`.`des_note` as `des_note`, 
       `hotels`.`feat_note` as `feat_note`, 
       `hotels`.`img_note` as `img_note`
from `hotels`
    inner join `features` on `hotels`.`id` = `features`.`hotel_id` 
where `features`.`name` in('Wifi in room','Wifi') 
group by hotels.id
```

Comment: What exactly do you want, an eloquent ORM query or a raw sql query with the DB facade?

Comment: Hi!! Thank you, for me its ok with the SQL query with db facade, i dont know How Is in SQL so i dont know How To do in orm also, Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You need one JOIN per feature:

```
select `hotels`.`name` as `name`, 
       `hotels`.`delegation_id` as `delegation`, 
       `hotels`.`jpcode` as `jpcode`, 
       `hotels`.`iata` as `iata`, 
       `hotels`.`checked` as `checked`, 
       `hotels`.`gen_note` as `gen_note`, 
       `hotels`.`des_note` as `des_note`, 
       `hotels`.`feat_note` as `feat_note`, 
       `hotels`.`img_note` as `img_note`
from `hotels`
    inner join `features` as `f1` on `hotels`.`id` = `f1`.`hotel_id`
    inner join `features` as `f2` on `hotels`.`id` = `f2`.`hotel_id`
where `f1`.`name` = 'Wifi in room'
    and `f2`.`name` = 'Wifi'
group by hotels.id
```